# Subclassing PFUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, xcode6, subclassing

I'm trying to subclass PFUser like this:

```
//  User.h

#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface User : PFUser <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userUsername;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userPassword;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *userEmail;

- (void)signUpUser;

@end

//  User.m

#import "User.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation User

@dynamic userUsername;
@dynamic userPassword;
@dynamic userEmail;

- (void)signUpUser {
    [self signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            NSLog(@"Success");
        } else {
            NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];   // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorString);
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

I Then do this to create a new user:

```
#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)signUpButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    // Sign up user with text from textfields.
    [self signUpUser:self.usernametextField.text password:self.passwordTextField.text email:self.emailTextField.text];
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)signUpUser:(NSString *)usernameString password:(NSString *)passwordString email:(NSString *)emailString {
    // Create a new user to sign up.
    User *user = [User user];
    user.username = usernameString;
    user.password = passwordString;
    user.email = emailString;
    [user signUpUser];
}
```

But why am I getting this? Am I forgetting something or am I not subclassing the PFUser in a correct way. The app works and creates a new user but I don't really understand why I'm getting this warning.

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'User *' with an expression of
>   type 'PFUser * __nonnull'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are have not implemented `user` method in `User` class. I suggest you to override `user` method to properly return an instance of `User` class.

In your case what is happening:
You create a `User` instance like this

```
User *user = [User user];
```

But you have no method `user` in your `User` class so you always fall back to `PFUser` class to handle this call and you get an instance of `PFUser` and that is why you get the warning.

Overriding `user` method in `User` class will solve the problem. Do it this way:

```
+(User*)user {
    return (User*)[PFUser user];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes of course, that makes sense. Didn't think about that. Thank you for explaining and pointing that out. But does return (User *)[[super class] user]; suffice? It' crasches with EXC_BAD_ACCESS @Vivek Molkar

Comment: try replacing `return (User*)[[super class] user];` with `return (User*)[PFUser user]`;